# How can I enable resource limit delegation for my not-root user using cgroups?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, kernel, cgroup, resource-limiting

I am trying to set up resource limit delegation for a specific user `myuser` on Ubuntu 20.04.5. The point is that I need to be able to control resource limits when running my rootless Podman container.

However, despite the numerous online tutorials on cgroups, I am at a loss as to how I'm supposed to achieve this.

On the official Podman website, it says that I can verify whether resource limit delegation is enabled by running the following command:

```
cat "/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-$(id -u).slice/user@$(id -u).service/cgroup.controllers"
```

But the `user.slice` folder doesn't exist. Then it says that in any case I can enable resource limit delegation for *all users* by modifying the file:

```
/etc/systemd/system/user@.service.d/delegate.conf
```

But the `user@.service.d` folder doesn't exist. Then I'm being told that I maybe need to install the `libcgroup` package, but when I run

```
apt-get install libcgroup
```

I get

```
Unable to locate package libcgroup
```

So what am I supposed to do to enable cgroups on Ubuntu 20.04.5 and set up resource limit delegation for `myuser`?

Please help...

Comment: `find /sys/fs/cgroup/* | grep "user@$(id -u).service/cgroup.controllers"` shows that it's located at `/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/user.slice/user-$(id -u).slice/user@$(id -u).service/cgroup.controllers`

Comment: @mchid Thank you for that. But after modifying my `cat...` command, I get an empty return value, i.e., can't delegate resource limits for that user. And the `delegate.conf` file is not existing anywhere.

Comment: [Would something like this work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557843/looking-for-a-consistent-way-to-configure-cgroups-on-ubuntu-14-04-desktop) You would need to install `cgroup-tools` Also, the package you were looking for is `libcgroup1` instead of `libcgroup` for some reason. Run `apt-cache search cgroup | grep cgroup` to list related packages.

Comment: If you're not a `vi` user, just use `nano` instead and you probably need to use `sudo` to run the commands in the linked answer or as root.

Comment: @mchid Thanks for that, now I was able to install the `libcgroup` package. But still, there is no `/etc/cgrules.conf` file. And still no `delegate.conf` file. I installed both the `libcgroup1` and `cgroup-tools` packages.

Comment: You sure? `/etc/cgrules.conf` [should be provided by the `cgroup-tools` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=cgrules.conf).

Comment: Also, I couldn't find a delegate.conf file anywhere from any package. Unless it's a file that you create manually. Not sure the method they were using in the tutorial but using the `/etc/cgrules.conf` file seems pretty straightforward. If possible, you might be able to use that instead of the delegate file.

Comment: @mchid Indeed, but the file is located at `/usr/share/doc/cgroup-tools/examples/cgrules.conf` instead of `/etc/cgrules.conf`. That seems strange, especially that it's inside a folder named `examples`. Am I supposed to copy that into `/etc/`? Why is there so little documentation on this? It's confusing, every step of the way.

Comment: Yeah, the `cgrules.conf` file is an **example file** located at `/usr/share/doc/cgroup-tools/examples/cgrules.conf` You can look to this file for examples. All you have to do is create your own file at `/etc/cgrules.conf` If the example configuration is what you want then copy the file to `/etc/cgrules.conf` and you can use that as a template.

Comment: The example shown in [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557843/looking-for-a-consistent-way-to-configure-cgroups-on-ubuntu-14-04-desktop) does not use the example file as a template and appears to only set limits for a `groupname:username`

Comment: @mchid Thanks for that. I will try that now. After modifying the file, am I supposed to restart some service? I don't see anything related to `cgroup`s or `cgconfig`s in the list of services, even though several tutorials suggest executing `service cgconfig restart`